# Working with tables in python-docx

Tags: python-docx

I have a small question about working with opened docx-file.
This is part of my code:

```
doc = Document(self.fileName[0])

for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
   self.cursor.insertText(paragraph.text + '\n')

for table_index, table in enumerate(doc.tables):
   self.cursor.insertText('Таблица {0}\n'.format(table_index+1))
   for row_index in range(len(table.rows)):
      for column_index in range(len(table.columns)):
         self.cursor.insertText(table.cell(row_index, column_index).text + '\t')
      self.cursor.insertText('\n')
   self.cursor.insertText('\n')
```

The question is can I find out where table is placed physicaly in the
original doc?
I need to display paragraphs and tables in the same order like in doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is not yet directly supported by the `python-docx` API. However you can find a workaround function for it here:
https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40
and a little further information may be found by searching on 'python-docx iter block items'.

The basic problem is that the Microsoft API for Word does not include a method for iterating block-level items in document order. Block-level items in Word are the paragraph and table objects. `python-docx` modeled the MS API as its starting point and so the `Document.paragraphs` and `Document.tables` properties were the first to be implemented. `Document.iter_block_items()` or perhaps just `Document.block_items` hasn't been implemented yet, although it's closer to the top of the enhancement list than many other features because it's frequently asked for.

In the meantime, you'll need to implement a workaround function in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reference to https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40, though had to do some updates to the code found, maybe due to changes over ~5 years, and ended up using:

```
from docx.document import Document
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.table import _Cell, Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph

def iter_block_items(parent):
    """
    Yield each paragraph and table child within *parent*, in document order.
    Each returned value is an instance of either Table or Paragraph. *parent*
    would most commonly be a reference to a main Document object, but
    also works for a _Cell object, which itself can contain paragraphs and tables.
    """
def iter_block_items(parent):
    # Get parrent element
    if isinstance(parent, Document):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")
    # Get children in parent element
    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for this:

```
###Import all necessary packages
from docx.opc.constants import RELATIONSHIP_TYPE as RT
from docx import *
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.text.paragraph import Run
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from docx.document import Document as doctwo
from docx.oxml.table import CT_Tbl
from docx.oxml.text.paragraph import CT_P
from docx.table import _Cell, Table
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.shared import Pt
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
from docx import Document as Document_compose
import pandas as pd
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from io import StringIO
import io
import csv
import base64


#Load the docx file into document object. You can input your own docx file in this step by changing the input path below:
document = Document('/Users/karthick/Desktop/iclouddrive/Work/QA/microchip datasheets/22100F-converted-latest.docx')




##This function extracts the tables and paragraphs from the document object
def iter_block_items(parent):
    """
    Yield each paragraph and table child within *parent*, in document order.
    Each returned value is an instance of either Table or Paragraph. *parent*
    would most commonly be a reference to a main Document object, but
    also works for a _Cell object, which itself can contain paragraphs and tables.
    """
    if isinstance(parent, doctwo):
        parent_elm = parent.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")

    for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
        if isinstance(child, CT_P):
            yield Paragraph(child, parent)
        elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
            yield Table(child, parent)


#This function extracts the table from the document object as a dataframe
def read_docx_tables(tab_id=None, **kwargs):
    """
    parse table(s) from a Word Document (.docx) into Pandas DataFrame(s)
    Parameters:
        filename:   file name of a Word Document
        tab_id:     parse a single table with the index: [tab_id] (counting from 0).
                    When [None] - return a list of DataFrames (parse all tables)
        kwargs:     arguments to pass to `pd.read_csv()` function
    Return: a single DataFrame if tab_id != None or a list of DataFrames otherwise
    """
    def read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs):
        vf = io.StringIO()
        writer = csv.writer(vf)
        for row in tab.rows:
            writer.writerow(cell.text for cell in row.cells)
        vf.seek(0)
        return pd.read_csv(vf, **kwargs)

#    doc = Document(filename)
    if tab_id is None:
        return [read_docx_tab(tab, **kwargs) for tab in document.tables]
    else:
        try:
            return read_docx_tab(document.tables[tab_id], **kwargs)
        except IndexError:
            print('Error: specified [tab_id]: {}  does not exist.'.format(tab_id))
            raise



#The combined_df dataframe will store all the content in document order including images, tables and paragraphs.
#If the content is an image or a table, it has to be referenced from image_df for images and table_list for tables using the corresponding image or table id that is stored in combined_df
#And if the content is paragraph, the paragraph text will be stored in combined_df
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['para_text','table_id','style'])
table_mod = pd.DataFrame(columns=['string_value','table_id'])

#The image_df will consist of base64 encoded image data of all the images in the document
image_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['image_index','image_rID','image_filename','image_base64_string'])

#The table_list is a list consisting of all the tables in the document
table_list=[]
xml_list=[]

i=0
imagecounter = 0


blockxmlstring = ''
for block in iter_block_items(document):
    if 'text' in str(block):
        isappend = False

        runboldtext = ''
        for run in block.runs:                        
            if run.bold:
                runboldtext = runboldtext + run.text

        style = str(block.style.name)

        appendtxt = str(block.text)
        appendtxt = appendtxt.replace("\n","")
        appendtxt = appendtxt.replace("\r","")
        tabid = 'Novalue'
        paragraph_split = appendtxt.lower().split()                

        isappend = True
        for run in block.runs:
            xmlstr = str(run.element.xml)
            my_namespaces = dict([node for _, node in ElementTree.iterparse(StringIO(xmlstr), events=['start-ns'])])
            root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr) 
            #Check if pic is there in the xml of the element. If yes, then extract the image data
            if 'pic:pic' in xmlstr:
                xml_list.append(xmlstr)
                for pic in root.findall('.//pic:pic', my_namespaces):
                    cNvPr_elem = pic.find("pic:nvPicPr/pic:cNvPr", my_namespaces)
                    name_attr = cNvPr_elem.get("name")
                    blip_elem = pic.find("pic:blipFill/a:blip", my_namespaces)
                    embed_attr = blip_elem.get("{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships}embed")
                    isappend = True
                    appendtxt = str('Document_Imagefile/' + name_attr + '/' + embed_attr + '/' + str(imagecounter))
                    document_part = document.part
                    image_part = document_part.related_parts[embed_attr]
                    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_part._blob)
                    image_base64 = image_base64.decode()                            
                    dftemp = pd.DataFrame({'image_index':[imagecounter],'image_rID':[embed_attr],'image_filename':[name_attr],'image_base64_string':[image_base64]})
                    image_df = image_df.append(dftemp,sort=False)
                    style = 'Novalue'
                imagecounter = imagecounter + 1

    elif 'table' in str(block):
        isappend = True
        style = 'Novalue'
        appendtxt = str(block)
        tabid = i
        dfs = read_docx_tables(tab_id=i)
        dftemp = pd.DataFrame({'para_text':[appendtxt],'table_id':[i],'style':[style]})
        table_mod = table_mod.append(dftemp,sort=False)
        table_list.append(dfs)
        i=i+1
    if isappend:
            dftemp = pd.DataFrame({'para_text':[appendtxt],'table_id':[tabid],'style':[style]})
            combined_df=combined_df.append(dftemp,sort=False)

combined_df = combined_df.reset_index(drop=True)
image_df = image_df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can refer to this link for a detailed explanation of how the code works:

https://github.com/kmrambo/Python-docx-Reading-paragraphs-tables-and-images-in-document-order-